# node js cluster - how it works

Tags: node.js

I tried creating workers and it works fine.  It has four cores, on multiple attempts, it shows message from only one worker.

```
    var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


if (cluster.isMaster) {
    var cpuCount = os.cpus().length ;
    console.log("No. of cpus:", cpuCount);
    for(var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i++) cluster.fork();

    cluster.on('listening', function(worker, address) {
        console.log('woker id:' + worker.id +' is now listening on port:' + address.port);
    });
} else {
    console.log("i'm a worker.. ... lets proceed");
    var server = app.listen(8082, function(req, res) {

        var host = server.address().address;
        var port = server.address().port;
        request(i18n.__('url.config'), function(error, response, body){
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            } else {
                console.log("Config error",error);
            }
        });
    }); // child process

}// else

//Listen for dying workers
cluster.on('exit', function (worker) {
    // Bring that ... ..er  back
    console.log('Worker %d died :', worker.id);
    cluster.fork();
});

cluster.on('online', function (worker) {
    // worker is alive
    console.log('Worker %d is alive :', worker.id);
});

app.get('/hey', function(req, res){
    console.log('Worker %d running!', cluster.worker.id);
    res.send('Hello World from worker ' + cluster.worker.id);
});
```

later I modified code to instantiate and create the creation of express object inside the worker(else loop).  Output is same.

```
    if (cluster.isMaster) {
    var cpuCount = os.cpus().length ;
    console.log("No. of cpus:", cpuCount);
    for(var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i++) cluster.fork();

    cluster.on('listening', function(worker, address) {
        console.log('woker id:' + worker.id +' is now listening on port:' + address.port);
    });
} else {
    var app = express();

    console.log("i'm a worker.. ... lets proceed");
    var server = app.listen(8082, function(req, res) {

        var host = server.address().address;
        var port = server.address().port;
        request(i18n.__('url.config'), function(error, response, body){
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            } else {
                console.log("Config error",error);
            }
        });

        app.get('/hey', function(req, res){
            console.log('Worker %d running!', cluster.worker.id);
            res.send('Hello World from worker ' + cluster.worker.id);
        });
    }); // child process

}// else
```

> node --debug server.js
>
> Debugger listening on port 5858
>
> No. of cpus: 4
>
> Debugger listening on port 5859
>
> Debugger listening on port 5860
>
> Debugger listening on port 5861
>
> Debugger listening on port 5862
>
> i'm a worker.. ... lets proceed
>
> woker id:1 is now listening on port:8082
>
> i'm a worker.. ... lets proceed
>
> i'm a worker.. ... lets proceed
>
> i'm a worker.. ... lets proceed
>
> woker id:4 is now listening on port:8082
>
> woker id:3 is now listening on port:8082
>
> woker id:2 is now listening on port:8082
>
> Worker 2 running!
>
> Worker 2 running!
>
> Worker 2 running!
>
> Worker 2 running!

Which way of worker creation is correct?  Since its listening on a port, does creation of express object globally, will cause any issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clustering in Node.js allows you to create separate processes which can share same server port.

When a worker is forked off of the main process, it re-runs the code from the beginning of the module. So it'll create the Express app, a route, and then listens on given port.

But how are requests divided up between the workers? Obviously they can't (and shouldn't) all be listening and responding to every single request that we get. To handle this, there is actually an embedded load-balancer within the cluster module that handles distributing requests between the different workers. On Linux and OSX (but not Windows) the round-robin (cluster.SCHED_RR) policy is in effect by default.

You might also be wondering how different processes can be sharing a single port. The difficult part about running so many processes that handle network requests is that traditionally only one can have a port open at once. The big benefit of cluster is that it handles the port-sharing for you, so any ports you have open, like for a web-server, will be accessible for all children. This is done via IPC, which means the master just sends the port handle to each worker.

cluster.fork() does start up a new V8 instance.

It should be used with caution. Each worker takes up system resources, so only spawn those that are really needed.

That being said, to answer your question, any of those two approaches is ok.

Since fork creates a new instance, creating of objects globally doesn't affect.

Below link explains about cluster.fork and child_process.fork
https://millermedeiros.github.io/mdoc/examples/node_api/doc/cluster.html

Comment: Thanks, for the xplanation and link.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use cluster by using core node js as well as PM2 package. In both the cases I successfully created the cluster and used it. I have added some details in the below blogs. Once go through it. It may provide some clarification.

https://jksnu.blogspot.com/2022/02/cluster-in-node-js-application.html

https://jksnu.blogspot.com/2022/02/cluster-management-in-node-js.html